# How to manage two threads, pynput mouse listener and while loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, pynput

I have a mouse listener:

```
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Button

def on_click(x, y, button):
    if button == Button.left:
    xy_dict["x"] = x
    xy_dict["y"] = y
    if button == Button.right:
        raise MyException(button)

with Listener(on_click=on_click) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

And I also have `main()` function from other script. It is supposed that `main()` takes `x` and `y` from mouse listener, but how can I unite these two threads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context manager method (i.e. `with`) is only useful if you want to be able to stop the listener. If you don't need that, simply start the listener:

```
listener = Listener(on_click=on_click)
listener.start()
```

It will automatically start as a new thread:

https://pythonhosted.org/pynput/mouse.html#monitoring-the-mouse

> A mouse listener is a `threading.Thread`, and all callbacks will be invoked from the thread.

The easiest method to access the `x` and `y` values would be to wrap this in a class and update instance attributes within the handler; or define two global variables (`x` and `y`).

Comment: I also add that there is `listener.stop()` which can be used at the end of program to stop thread. And after `.stop()` we can use `listener.join()`